# Load infinite amount of articles (Lazy Load)

Tags: jquery

I found a script that would lazy load x number of articles, but what if the total number of articles always changes every day?  Is there a way to make the items calculate the total amount in a set (if that makes sense?).  So instead of 999, or a specific number in the items variable.

The problem is I'm never going to know how many articles are added to the site.

Here is my JSFiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/robertallenbaker/maezdhe2/4/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.sidebar-article-entry').hide();
$('.sidebar-article-entry:lt(5)').show();
var items =  999;
var shown =  5;
$('.more-articles-link').click(function () {
    shown = $('.sidebar-article-entry:visible').size()+5;
    if(shown< items) {
        $('.sidebar-article-entry:lt('+shown+')').slideDown();
    }
    else {
        $('.sidebar-article-entry:lt('+items+')').show();
        $('.more-articles-link').hide();
    }
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`slice()`](http://api.jquery.com/slice/) for this. It filters elements based on  start and end  indexes

Then just compare `shown` to `length` of the elements collection

```
  var $entries = $('.sidebar-article-entry'),
      shown = 5;

  $entries.filter(':gt(4)').hide();    

  $('.more-articles-link').click(function() {
    $entries.slice(shown, shown + 5).show();
    shown += 5;
    if (shown >= $entries.length) {
      $(this).hide()
    }
  });
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/maezdhe2/6/)**</kbd>

Comment: Awesome!  Thank you so much!